# ssis ftp task error The operation timed out

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis, ftp

I am using sql server 2005. The sql agent calls a scheduled job which includes 4 steps. Each step calls an ssis package and each package includes a single ftp task. Each ftp task, downloads a file. Every once in a while and without any particular pattern one of those tasks fails showing a timed out error while downloading the file. The step fails and the job sequence is broken. However:

-The file is always completely downloaded.

-The ftp server is set to passive.

-The ftp connection managers are set to passive.

The only reasonable assumption from my point of view is that this has nothing to do with my set up or my ssis packages and it is a network operations issue. Am i missing anything though?

Assuming that i will not be able to solve this, is there any way to check if my file is completely and correctly downloaded (checksum perhaps?) and move on to the next step, ignoring the ftp error?

Comment: Logging is incredibly limited with the old SSIS deployment methods. Unfortunately, you're using an unsupported version of SQL Server here, so resources are going to be limited. If you *are* getting a time out, my guess would be that the SQL Server can't connect to the FTP host; but we have nothing to really go on here I'm afraid other than an error and knowledge of *what* you are doing.

Comment: Isolate the FTP step and set the agent to retry that step on failure. If the file exists, don't download it again. Kind of kludgy but I've run into the same issue and this is how I dealt with it.